# Nested Query error

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, wsdl

I have below nested query where Line Item is child of Inc Transaction and all field names are valid still I am getting errored out Can someone please help me here?

NESTED QUERY:

```
select Account_Abs_abv__c,
(select Call_Detail_abv__r.Product_vod__c,
Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__c from Incident_Transaction_Line_Items_abv__r)
from Incident_Transaction_abv__c
```

ERROR:

> INVALID_TYPE:
>
> Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__c from Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__r)
>
> ^
>
> ERROR at Row:3:Column:40
>
> Didn't understand relationship 'Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Try using `Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__c` instead of `Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__r`

Comment: hi Novarg! It is not working. Got this from here. Can you please write the query for me? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: One way to find the correct name is to use Setup -> Create -> Objects -> Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv and click on the lookup field to Incident_Transaction_abv which is probably called Incident_Transaction_abv. You will see the name you need to use in the "Child Relationship Name" of that page. Take exactly that name and add a __r suffix to it.

Comment: If not check the WSDL. Setup > Develop > API > Generate WSDL > enterprise WSDL and check for the correct API name there

Comment: or, if using eclipse ide, the schema explorer will build the query for you